# UIWebView and MIMEType image in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios8

I have a compatibility issue here between iOS8 and iOS7

```
NSData *saimage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"/9j/4AA........"  options:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

UIWebView *securityimageImg ;

securityimageImg = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 238, 35, 75, 75)];
securityimageImg.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[securityimageImg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
securityimageImg.delegate = self;
[securityimageImg loadData: saimage MIMEType:@"image/gif"  textEncodingName: @"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:securityimageImg];

UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:saimage];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake( 238, 105, 75, 75);

[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

In the above code,I used a `NSData` object with image as encoded text. Then, I use the sane for populating my web view and the `UIImage`.

Now, both `UIWebView` and `UIImageView` display images in `iOS7` 
Where-as *only* `UIImageView` displays image in `iOS8`.

> So, my UIWebView fails for MIMEType : image/gif in iOS8

I didn't get any loading issues with the `UIWebView` (checked the `didFailLoadWithError` delegate)

Am I missing anything here.?

**Xcode 6:** Beta 6

**Update:** Tested in iOS8 golden build. Issue still exists!

Comment: Did you got any log message ?

Comment: No Jagen. I checked in the Safari using developer menu. I see 2 pages rendered.. (only in iOS8.. where-as only one in iOS7) One page was blank.. and the other was what I am looking for. For some reasons, the one with blank page is appearing in simulator. I cant understand this behavior!